# I am following JavaScript course on Codecademy but where are the events?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have reached the point where we have to work on Blackjack game project but haven't seen any reference to events and checked the later part of course too but still nothing related to events is there.

Do you think that this course is of any use?

Please recommend me a source from where I can learn JavaScript in less time, I mean some fast track course.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend CodeAcademy for JavaScript. Take a look over here: https://gist.github.com/3162648 codeavengers is much better in my opinion. Tutorials on CodeAcademy were quite unstructured last time I checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything from Lynda.com. This should be just fine: http://www.lynda.com/JavaScript-tutorials/Essential-Training-2011/81266-2.html?srchtrk=index%3A2%0Alinktypeid%3A2%0Aq%3Ajavascript%0Apage%3A1%0As%3Arelevance%0Asa%3Atrue%0Aproducttypeid%3A2

Also if you want to use tutsplus, you can find 2 very good JavaScript Fundamentals tutorials: https://tutsplus.com/?s=javascript+fundamentals&post_type=all

You should also consider buying *JavaScript : The Good Parts* by Douglas Crockford, *JavaScript : The Definitive Guide* by David Flanagan and *JavaScript Patterns* by Stoyan Stefanof if you want to get up to speed with everything that JavaScript has to offer.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want learn javascript, but you probably will like this course of JQuery. On 30 days you will know thing that you ever dream.

https://tutsplus.com/course/30-days-to-learn-jquery/

I hope this help in your study. Bye!